# Change <fluent-select> and <fluent-option> background color in CSS

Tags: html, css, fluent-ui

I'm trying to change the background colours of the and elements in CSS. Preferably, I'd use no Javascript (I want the solution to be as simple as possible) and no React (I'm not set up with it). I want to change it to the "accent" appearance, which is a blue by default or to a custom colour. This is the code I'm using to create the select component:

```html
      <fluent-select title="Select a page to navigate to">
        <fluent-option value="1" onclick="console.info('Beginning clicked.')">Beginning</fluent-option>
        <fluent-option value="2">Middle</fluent-option>
        <fluent-option value="3">End</fluent-option>
      </fluent-select>
```

I tried this CSS code to change the colour:

```css
fluent-select {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This turned the element's colour red while the page was loading, but then turned back to white. Somehow, I'm able to change the font colour with `colour: #FFFFF;` but not the background colour. Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm assuming you can't do this based on the lack of comments and answers?